# I am trying to load a PDF in Webview Activity. PDF loads fine but few images inside the pdf are not rendering properly. Is this the code problem?

Tags: android

Setting up Webview to load PDF.

Cant figure out the issue if its code problem or PDF.
I am using JoanZapata android library.

```
private void loadPdf() {
        try {
            videoPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            videoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            pdfview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            findApiFrom(getIntent().getExtras().getString("PDF"), Constants.AnalysticsParams.VIEW);
            Log.v("WEB", "PDF FILE SIZE " + file.isFile());
            Log.e("url pdf", "url : " + file.toString());

            pdfview.fromFile(file).defaultPage(1)
                    .showMinimap(false).enableSwipe(true).swipeVertical(true).load();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(WebviewActivity.this, "Can't open this file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There are many possible errors. Do you see anything in your logcat?

Comment: E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaf773f00. A warning in logcat.